# Should I call jQuery.off after removing the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I am registering a click listener on a DOM element via `jQuery.on()`. If later on that element is removed from the DOM -- maybe indirectly, e.g. by by replacing some parent's content via `$(parent).html(...)`, should I still bother to remove my handler via `jQuery.off()`?

Even if the element will no longer trigger any event, I am worried about potential memory leaks. Does either jQuery or the browser take care of that and discard all registered handlers once an element is removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Even if the element will no longer trigger any event, I am worried about potential memory leaks.

This is very good concern. To answer your question, take a look at `$.fn.html` [implementation](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.html). From there you will learn that `html` will try to clean up stored event data:

```
// Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
    jQuery.cleanData(getAll(elem, false));
    elem.innerHTML = value;
}
```

So in this case manually calling `.off()` is not necessary. However..

You need to remember that you should never ever try to remove elements with native methods like `removeChild` or setting `innerHTML`, since in this case there will be a memory leak for sure (if some data is stored, events are registered by jQuery, etc.). In this case it's more reliable to actually deregister event handlers with `.off` method. Or better use event propagation and instead or `html('')` use `$.fn.remove`.

Comment: But why the browser keeps those in memory? why do we need to remove them explicitly?

Comment: @SubinJacob Because jQuery stores `data` and `event` data in intermediate object. If elements are removed from DOM it may happen that related data will remain in internal cache (e.g. you bind event with `.on` and then remove element with `removeChild` or `innerHTML = ''` on parent). jQuery's `html('')`, `empty()`, `remove()`, etc. make sure to remove corresponding elements data from cache.

Comment: Oh thats it. Then its related to jQuery only, not browser, right? It would be pretty ok if we bound event using pure vanilla js.

Comment: Yes, this is specific jQuery-related leak in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to call jQuery.off before removing your node, especially if it's a one page application which can contains a lot of events registered.